# aws cloudwatch cli put-metric-data to AWS namespace

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

I would like to test some AWS CloudWatch alarms linked to some AWS metrics(ApiGateway • 5XXError). I try to manually add data to this, without messing up my API.
I try the command:

```
aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --namespace AWS/ApiGateway --metric-name 5XXError --dimensions ApiName=SpacesApi --value 1
```

But I get the response:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the PutMetricData operation: The value AWS/ for parameter Namespace is invalid.
```

I'm pretty sure this is possible, since I've done this in the past, but I can't make it work.

Comment: To avoid conflicts with Amazon Web Services service namespaces, you should not specify a namespace that begins with `AWS/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per AWS documentation:

> A number of AWS services publish their own metrics in namespaces
> beginning with " AWS " You can also publish custom metric data using
> your own namespace (as long as it doesn’t begin with " AWS ").
>
> **Note:**
>
> You cannot specify a namespace that begins with " AWS ". Namespaces
> that begin with " AWS " are reserved for use by Amazon Web Services
> products.

In your case, `AWS/ApiGateway` namespace is reserved for Amazon API Gateway to publish metrics to CloudWatch, so it's not possible.

References: [Publishing custom metric data to CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-cloudwatch-publish-custom-metrics.html)

Comment: That is true for the SDK, but from the CLI it should be possible.

Comment: @Barosanu240 Both SDK and CLI commands eventually will make PutMetricData API call: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_PutMetricData.html

Comment: @Barosanu240, it is applicable for both SDK or CLI.